# how can i use BackdropFilter in custompainter

Tags: flutter

I want to make something similar to the picture
[sample pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnzNW.jpg)

So I wrote the following codes

```
Positioned(
                  top: 200,
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60,
                    width: 339,
                    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                    child: CustomPaint(
                      painter: BottomNavBar(),
                      child: Container(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0)),
                        child: BackdropFilter(
                          filter:
                              ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 20, sigmaY: 20),
                          child: CustomPaint(painter: BottomNavBar()),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
```

But the output is as follows
[output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNjyh.jpg)

The borders around the circle also disappear
How can I solve it?
should i pass image to custompainter and use BackdropFilter ? how ?
tnx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

BackdropFilter applies the Filter to everything behind the child Widget.
ImageFiltered applies the Filter to the child.

If that is not the cause of the problem you might need to wrap the blurred widget in a ClipPath to cut off the extra parts.